# How to align button to right and vertical center inside a division?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, html, lightning-button

I want to display a text and two buttons inside a `<div>` in a `<aura:component>`. When I use the following code:

```
<div style="background-color:blue; margin:2px; padding:10px;" >
   <span>Page 1 of 0 </span> <span><lightning:button label="Prev" disabled="{!v.staywellPrevDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellPrev}"/><lightning:button label="Next" disabled="{!v.staywellNextDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellNext}"/></span>
</div>
```

I got the result like this: 
[image]

But, I want the buttons to align right. So I changed the code to this:

```
<div style="background-color:blue; margin:2px; padding:10px;" >
   <span>Page 1 of 0 </span> <span style="float: right;"><lightning:button label="Prev" disabled="{!v.staywellPrevDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellPrev}"/><lightning:button label="Next" disabled="{!v.staywellNextDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellNext}"/></span>
</div>
```

But, the result I got is like this: 
[image]

When the buttons are aligned right, they are not in vertical center of the `<div>`. I have used salesforce's `slds-float_right` class and also used `vertical-align: middle`. But, everything gives the same result. 
So, how can I align these buttons to right while keeping them in the vertical center of the `<div>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used float on the button so they are taken out from the "normal" flow you can set overflow to "hidden" or "auto" in this case like this

```
  <div style="background-color:blue; margin:2px; padding:10px;overflow: auto;" >
   <span>Page 1 of 0 </span> <span style="float: right;"><lightning:button label="Prev" disabled="{!v.staywellPrevDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellPrev}"/><lightning:button label="Next" disabled="{!v.staywellNextDisabled}" onclick="{!c.staywellNext}"/></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.. it worked.